# How to get value of specified field in an array of objects in mongodb

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I want to get values of specified field from the `users` array.
Something like `{_id: {$in: this.users}}`. The difference is that `users` is an array of objects and I want to get the `_id` field of each object in this array.
Here's a code sample:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    username: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    password: {type: String, required: true,},
    email: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    role: {type: String, enum: ['user'], required: true},
    name: String,
    phoneNumber: Number,
    companies: [{
        _company: {type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Company'},
        points: Number
    }],
    points: Number,
    created_at: Date,
    updated_at: Date
})
```

And I want write this middleware for mongoose UserSchema:

```
UserSchema.pre('remove', function(next) {
    this.model('Company').update(
        {_id: {$in: ??????????????????}},
        {$pull: {users: this._id}},
        next()
    )
})
```

But I don't know how to retrieve `_company` field from companies using `$in`.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Where is the `users` field of `UserSchema`?

Comment: Sory, I didn't change it after Copy-Paste. It should be another Schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this

```
UserSchema.pre('remove', function(next) {
    var ids = this.companies.map(function(o) {return o._company;});
    this.model('Company').update(
        {_id: {$in: ids}},
    //...
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok so as far as I understood, you have an array named `users`, that has your User Objects. And you want to get just the `_id` field values from that array. So you can do something like this :

```
var ids = users.map(function(user){ return user._id });
```

Now that you have the `_id` values of the users, you can go ahead with your query.

Comment: I have an array, named companies and there are my companies objects. What I want to get is _company field from array named companies.

Comment: Do this : `var _companies = companies.map(function(company){ return company._company });`

Comment: This will return the _company field from each object in your companies array.